# href links work locally but not live?

Tags: html, css, href

Href links are working fine locally but not live.
Looking into it, I see that there is an issue with hover states on touchscreen devices. I thought that was my only issue, but it seems as though the links are not clicking through at all now.

UPDATE - Discovered I'm also getting a console error message as follows:

*Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lC8A0P4y00' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.*

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/yiddishtwist?fref=ts' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Refused to display 'https://soundcloud.com/loya/sets/yto-forthcoming-debut-album' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/yiddishtwist?fref=ts">
                    <img src="images/facebook.png" height="62" alt="facebook link" /></a>
```

There is no JS on the site, with the exception of the following, copy pasted from Mailchimp and placed inside my head:

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer'); document.createElement('section'); 
document.createElement('article'); document.createElement('aside'); 
document.createElement('nav');</script>
```

I can't imagine that CSS is interfering, but just in case, here is my image hover state:
CSS

```
section img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

}

Grateful for any thoughts.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site? That link should be working just fine. Maybe you don't have the image saved in the correct directory (although this shouldn't affect the link either)?

Comment: Update - Console informs me: "Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lC8A0P4y00' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. "

Comment: `images/facebook.png` must be on your Server for you to see it. Is it. Give your image a height. Also, your JavaScript won't do anything until you `.appendChild()` or something of the like. Your link is fine. I just tested it. Do you have another `<script>` tag with it's `src` set? We need to see those too.

Comment: here's the link to the site: www.yiddishtwist.com Images and everything are there, everything is on the server. When I hover over the links, I see the link, but clicking helpeth not.

Comment: ctrl+ click on the link works... doing some more investigation. It looks like sometimes JS can hijack clicking like this... but the code you provided shouldn't do it.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. No console errors. Are you sure you're not just trying to advertise to us?

Comment: This may be it: in Firefox I get... [23:39:08.259] Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.facebook.com/yiddishtwist?fref=ts does not permit framing. Does it think I am trying to embed in an iframe type wrapper? Perhaps I need a another way rather than wrapping an a href around my img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole website is sat in one big frame, the actual site is http://yto.lemezandfridel.com/

The Facebook, Youtube and Soundcloud links are refusing to load in a frame, thanks to [protection against clickjacking attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

The short-term solution is to add `target="_top"` to those links and they will load in the parent page and not the frame.

The long-term solution is not to frame your page in the first place

Comment: That's interesting. So a subdirectory of a main domain is not the equal of hosting directly on the domain? Good to know...

Comment: Actually the issue is that one website has been embedded in the other using a `<frame>` element. Not many people would build a site like that any more

Comment: aha. it's a fix while I transfer the domain away from one provider, I figured it wouldn't matter as a temp solution. Always learning! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/yiddishtwist?fref=ts" target="_blank">
```

Or alternatively using JS:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/yiddishtwist?fref=ts', '_blank')"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. What;s the diff btw _blank and _top target?

Comment: Hah yep :) _blank will be a new tab.